# Remove member from #general channel on Slack

Tags: slack

I tried but there seems to be no way I can remove a member from general channel on Slack, nor can the member himself quit. Any way around there? It's okay if I can delete the channel altogether.

Answer (score 6):

The `#general` channel is kind of special in Slack. While you don't have full control over this channel, there are a few things you can do if you don't want to use it the way its intended by Slack:

- Rename it to something less important (and then name another channel `general`)
- Restrict post permissions (e.g. by restricting to owners only)

That way you can ignore it and use other channels as your `#general` channel instead.

I would not delete it (and frankly not sure if you even can), because some Slack apps might rely on its existence.

Comment: @Deepak Sharma If this answer solved the question, please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the checkmark. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Agreed with Erik, seems like you can't remove an user from **# general** even though you're the owner, in my case a particular user has left my company & we're unable to remove him from **# general** & **# random** . So if you remove that user from workspace rather than in every channel, then automatically they'll be removed from those two channels (you don't see their name). You can do that this way :

> click on workspace on top left in slack desktop app --> Administration --> Manage members
>   --> click on left three dots --> Click on Deactivate account

Comment: This worked like a charm for me

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Might be an old question but I've just managed to do this...

1. Login to Slack.com using a browser.
2. Go to **Settings & Administration > Manage Members**.
3. Scroll down and find the users you want to remove.
4. Click the 3 dots to the right of their name.
5. Select **Deactivate Account**.
6. The member/s will be removed from the workspace and all channels.

Answer (score 1):

We have some staff members who were furloughed and will be coming back, assuming this isn't the end of the world. We don't want them "working" so we are removing them from all channels that are work related (so they can still see our "recipes" channel and our "movies" channels, for example), and because of that I do not want to remove them from the whole Space. The only solution I had was to make work channels "private," and to tell the remaining staff to not post anything in #General until everyone is back.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is a full member they will be in general channel by default and there is no option to remove.

However, if you update the user to a single or multi channel guest you can remove them from the general channel!

Hope this helps people in the future.